# regular expression to match data

Tags: java, regex

I have array of items like below

```
[1;233,2;345,3;656]
```

am looking for regular expression to save my array like below

```
[233,345,656]
```

so which discards value before semi colon

Comment: Do you want to split by the semicolon, and then get only numbers that are to the left of a comma, is that it?

Comment: @Renan : split by the semicolon and then get numbers right after semicolon [233,345,656] and discard data before semicolon

Answer (score 3):

perhaps try regex replace on `[0-9]+;` with an empty string. If there is only going to be a single digit then the + is not needed. In the case of a single digit it may also be easier to just find a semicolon, delete it and the preceding character.

Comment: your regex is working, but after splitting its saving data like below [,233,,345,,656] how can i avoid this extra comma

Comment: @vishwa: smitec suggests you to make a replace with an empty string, not splitting

Answer (score 0):

```
replaceAll("\d;" ,"")
```

If your number of digits is not fixed at one and can change, you can use `\d+`

Answer (score 0):

That'd be something like:

```
;([^,;]+)$1
```

That means at least one semicolon as a starting character, then one or more characters that are neither a semicolon nor a comma. Finally, it marks only the part to the right of the semicolon as the desired result.

I'm not sure this is the syntax for Java, specifically. I'm more of a .NET guy. But you can work your way from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your array string by **,** to get the couples and than by **;** to find the numbers.

**PHP:**

```
$string= "[1;233,2;345,3;656]";
$temp=explode(",", $string); //to get couples like 1;233
print_r($temp);
$result=array();
for($i=0; $i<count($temp);$i++){
    $temp1=explode(";", $temp[$i]);
    array_push($result,$temp1[1] );//take second value 233
}
print_r($result);
```

Output: $couple_array: `Array ( [0] => [1;233 [1] => 2;345 [2] => 3;656] )`

Output: $array: `Array ( [0] => 233 [1] => 345 [2] => 656] )`

**Java:**

```
String str = "[1;233,2;345,3;656]";
String[] temp = str.split(",");//to get couples like 1;233
int size=temp.length;
String[] result=new String[size];
for(int i =0; i < size ; i++){
    String[] temp1=str.split(";");//take second value 233
    result[i]=temp1[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is typed with integers, regular expressions are out of scope. 
You should consider creating a new array with integers of value superior to, say, 99 (3-digit integers).

However, if your array contains Strings, here's the regex you want:

```
Pattern yourPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D)\\d{1,2}(?=\\D)"); 
// this will find 1 or 2 digit numbers preceded and followed by anything but a digit
```

**Edit**: for the regular expressions solution, I assume we are talking about the String representation of an Array. Hence the check for non-numerical characters. 
If instead you were iterating over an array of String, then you could probably use `Integer.valueOf("12")` and compare if to int value 99. That is, if you're positive your Strings will always represent an Integer (or handle a NumberFormatException otherwise).